# How to use censoring at left point of zero in GAMLSS?

Tags: gamlss

How do I apply GAMLSS tools to left-censored regression at a specific point?
I know there exists `gamlss.cens` package, but it seems can not be censored at zero.

Answer (score 0):

In R:

```r
install.packages('gamlss.cens')
library(gamlss.cens)
?gen.cens
```

The function `gen.cens()` allows the user to
generate a "censored" version of any gamlss distribution,
e.g.

```r
gen.cens(NO,type="left")
```

for a left censored normal.

The censored cases are indicated in the data set,
where the response y is a `Surv()` object as in the R survival package.

[Note that censoring is sometimes confused with truncation.
For a truncated distribution use the `gamlss.tr`  R package,
and then use the function `gen.trun()`.]